# Modifying specific characters in text input (C++)

Tags: c++, special-characters

I receive text with special characters  (such as á) so I have to manually search and replace each one with code (in this case `"&aacute;"`)

I would like to have code to search and replace such instances automatically after user input. Since I'm a noob, I'll show you the code I have so far - however meager it may be.

```
// Text fixer
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
string input;
cout << "Input text";
cin >> input;
// this is where I'm at a loss. How should I manipulate the variable?
cout << input;
return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An easy method is to use an array of substitution strings:

```
std::string  replacement_text[???];
```

The idea is that you use the incoming character as the index into the array and extract the replacement text.

For example:

```
replacement_text[' '] = "&nbsp;";
// ...
std::string new_string = replacement_text[input_character];
```

Another method is to use `switch` and `case` to convert the character.

Alternative techniques are a lookup table and `std::map`.
The lookup table could be an array of mapping structures:

```
struct Entry
{
  char key;
  std::string replacement_text;
}
```

Search the table using the `key` field to match the incoming character.  Use the `replacement_text` to get the replacement text.

Comment: How do you propose to handle multibyte encodings, such as UTF-8?

Comment: The incoming character whether UTF-8 or UTF-16 represents an integer, and can still be used as an index.  The type of the array can be `std::string` or `std::basic_string<wchar>` or another string type.